# Does a list of people mentioned in the bible who got saved exist?

Tags: bible

I am studying about being saved. According to scripture :

> Ephesians 2 : 8 - For by grace you have been saved through faith; and
>   that not of yourselves, it is the gift of God;

I want to study about the list of people mentioned in the bible who got saved. Explicitly I am looking for the one's who were like against God/Away from God and then got saved. Best example is, Apostle Paul. Are there any other in old and new testaments who were away from God and then saved?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  When you have a moment, please take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour  This is how we are different to other sites: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809

Comment: Three people have voted to close this question. Perhaps because there is no such "list" in the Bible, apart from those Old Testament characters whose faith in God and in His promises assured them of their reward. Go to Hebrews chapter 11.

Answer (score 1):

The Catholic Church mentions such a list in its’ **martyrology**.

> Before the amazing 4th century, Christians were parochial and even patriotic in their veneration of saints. Rome celebrated the martyrs who had died at Rome, Constantinople celebrated the martyrs who had died at Constantinople, Antioch celebrated the martyrs who had died at Antioch, and so on. It never occurred to the folks in Rome to celebrate the saints of Antioch, or vice versa: celebrating a saint involved walking out to see his tomb. But in the 4th century a unique group of saints broke this pattern and set us on the path to the celebration of all saints. Who were they?
>
> **The saints of the Bible.**
>
> The saints of the Bible were familiar names throughout the Church. Texts like Hebrews 11 and Sirach 44-50, read everywhere, held up the great men and women of Salvation History as examples to follow and heroes to venerate. For the church in Jerusalem, however, the saints of Scripture were also the local martyrs: just as Rome had a list of days for celebrating the martyrs of Rome, Jerusalem had a cycle of liturgical commemorations of the biblical saints. When 4th-century pilgrims brought Jerusalem’s liturgies back to their home dioceses, they brought with them the practice of liturgically commemorating the biblical saints—and implicitly, they created the practice of commemorating saints that were not local. Unwittingly, they had planted the seed of the universal sanctoral cycle.
>
> Biblical saints have been a fixture in the liturgical year ever since, but most people don’t know about them. With the exception of a few prominent New Testament figures and one feast day in the Extraordinary Form, they are not mentioned in the Liturgy of the Hours or in the Roman Missal. But it turns out there is another liturgical book entirely dedicated to the commemoration of saints: the Martyrology. You’ve seen one of those liturgical calendars that lists saints’ days? They get their information from the Martyrology—and for any given day they leave out most of what the Martyrology offers.
>
> Here’s the punchline: the Church celebrates St. Abraham (Oct. 9), St. Moses (Sept. 4), St. Gideon (Sept. 26), and other great saints of the Old and New Testaments liturgically. They are part of the liturgical year. I have a complete list of biblical saints’ days at the end of this post: Saints of the Bible: [A Complete List of Their Feasts in the Old and New Calendars](http://drandmrsholmes.com/blog/2015/11/01/saints-of-the-bible-a-complete-list-of-their-feasts-in-the-old-and-new-calendars/)

Answer (score 0):

In Acts 1v15 about a hundred and twenty.
Acts 4v4 about five thousand.
Acts 21v20 "ten thousand" not literally necessarily just a very large number.
There is then in Acts a progression from relatively few to a wide spread movement.
Romans 11v4 might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the verses I know...

Those who showed kindness to the people who Christ considered as His brethren..

Matthew 25:32-40 ISV 
32 All the nations will be assembled in front of him, and he will cull them out, one from another, like a shepherd separates sheep from goats. 33 He will put the sheep on his right but the goats on his left. 34 “Then the king will say to those on his right, ‘Come, you who have been blessed by my Father! Inherit the kingdom prepared for you from the foundation of the world, 35 because I was hungry, and you gave me something to eat. I was thirsty, and you gave me something to drink. I was a stranger, and you welcomed me. 36 I was naked, and you clothed me. I was sick, and you took care of me. I was in prison, and you visited me.’ 37 “Then the righteous will say to him, ‘Lord, when did we see you hungry and give you something to eat, or thirsty and give you something to drink?  38 When did we see you as a stranger and welcome you, or see you naked and clothe you? 39 When did we see you sick or in prison, and visit you?’ 40 The king will answer them, ‘I tell all of you with certainty, since you did it for one of the least important of these brothers of mine, you did it for me.’

A Great Multitude from the Tribulation

Revelation 7:9-17 KJV 
 9 After this I beheld, and, lo, a great multitude, which no man could number, of all nations, and kindreds, and people, and tongues, stood before the throne, and before the Lamb, clothed with white robes, and palms in their hands; 10 And cried with a loud voice, saying, Salvation to our God which sitteth upon the throne, and unto the Lamb. 11 And all the angels stood round about the throne, and about the elders and the four beasts, and fell before the throne on their faces, and worshipped God, 12 Saying, Amen: Blessing, and glory, and wisdom, and thanksgiving, and honour, and power, and might, be unto our God for ever and ever. Amen. 13 And one of the elders answered, saying unto me, What are these which are arrayed in white robes? and whence came they? 14 And I said unto him, Sir, thou knowest. And he said to me, These are they which came out of great tribulation, and have washed their robes, and made them white in the blood of the Lamb. 15 Therefore are they before the throne of God, and serve him day and night in his temple: and he that sitteth on the throne shall dwell among them. 16 They shall hunger no more, neither thirst any more; neither shall the sun light on them, nor any heat. 17 For the Lamb which is in the midst of the throne shall feed them, and shall lead them unto living fountains of waters: and God shall wipe away all tears from their eyes.

144,000 from the Tribes of Israel

Revelation 7:1-4 KJV 1 And after these things I saw four angels standing on the four corners of the earth, holding the four winds of the earth, that the wind should not blow on the earth, nor on the sea, nor on any tree. 2 And I saw another angel ascending from the east, having the seal of the living God: and he cried with a loud voice to the four angels, to whom it was given to hurt the earth and the sea, 3 Saying, Hurt not the earth, neither the sea, nor the trees, till we have sealed the servants of our God in their foreheads. 4 And I heard the number of them which were sealed: and there were sealed an hundred and forty and four thousand of all the tribes of the children of Israel.

The Faithful (Forefathers, Prophets, Kings, Judges)

Hebrews 11:4-40
Abel, Enoch, Noah, Abraham, Isaac, Jacob, Sarah, Joseph, Moses, Rahab, Gedeon, Barak, Samson, Jepthae, David, Samuel, the prophets, those who were resurrected along with Christ...

The Thief on the Cross

Luke 23:42-43 KJV 
42 And he said unto Jesus, Lord, remember me when thou comest into thy kingdom. 
43 And Jesus said unto him, Verily I say unto thee, To day shalt thou be with me in paradise.

The Children and the likes of the children

Matthew 18:3 KJV And said, Verily I say unto you, Except ye be converted, and become as little children, ye shall not enter into the kingdom of heaven.
Mat 19:14 KJV But Jesus said, Suffer little children, and forbid them not, to come unto me: for OF SUCH is the kingdom of heaven.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is a resounding YES! However, it is not a popular subject in many circles. The reason for its unpopular reception can be attributed to a less than adequate knowledge of salvation.

If you are wanting to study how people, after the death of Christ, which is the New Covenant, were saved and what their names are, you can find these in the book of Acts. In that book, you will find the following information that will give you a greater understanding for your own personal use as well as any evangelistic effort you feel led to perform. In the book of Acts, you will find people's names, who spoke to them the gospel, what they told them, how the people responded in receiving the message of salvation. The book of Acts contains every biblically listed example of conversion after the New Covenant was established. I hope this helps. May God bless you in your search.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by actually quoting from the book of Acts to give examples.